# How to create a new link with <a> tag?

Tags: html, github, hyperlink

I would like to ask a question about href with `<a>` tag.
For example, in the website form Bill Gates, the first link says https://www.gatesnotes.com/, but then when I click a new link in the page ,  the link changes into https://www.gatesnotes.com/About-Bill-Gates/Summer-Books-2021 like this and goes to a new page. How do I do the same thing?
I did `<a href ='index.html/life'>life</a>` and clicked the link but it says "Your file couldn’t be accessed". what I think is I need a new file to show a new page. but I don't know how to make a new file because if I make a file name with 'life' for example, HTML code doesn't seem to work. it might be wrong. but is there is any way. Please teach me the solution. I used github to post my website in public. but I just started using it. so I'm not sure exactly how to use it honestly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called `life.html` and use  `<a href ='life.html'>life</a>` instead.

Make sure you place it in the same directory as index.html or the path of href should change accordingly.

Comment: Do I have to makeb a new HTML file everytime to show a new page? For example, when  a website is about a blog, I guess that I need to make tons of HTML files to show articles.

Comment: Yes, ideally each new page you should have a different html. If you don't want that you can look into Single Page application frameworks like angular/react etc., There the ui is constructed dynamically.

Comment: Hey Kyo, you could use PHP and databases if you don't want to create a new HTML file everytime. All content is in a central database and a page called displayer.php can access it.

Comment: Yeah please don't suggest SPA's before suggesting the much simpler server-side option.